# Need advice on use of Visualforce page vs Lightning Web Components

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, custom-button, list, quickaction

I am trying to create a button on a list view in salesforce that, when clicked, will open a popup dialog of sorts. I would expect the button to be at the top of the list view, directly alongside the 'New' button, and the dialog to look similar to the dialog / popup that appears when clicking 'New' (with different content and fields of course). The goal is that the popup would contain a dropdown list, allowing the user to select a 'List__c' record, and then click a 'Finish' button. When clicking finish, all the checked records from the list view (in this case they are account records) are created as related fields to new entries on the 'List__c' object. Just to summarize, this means that there has to be a way to pass all the checked values, AND the value selected on the drop down.

I have been researching solutions to this. I really would like to use Lightning Web Components, because they are more modern and I have seen several sources indicate that they are the recommended solution, as Visualforce pages are getting sort of old and out dated. I have figured out the basics of LWC, but I am stuck on the list view button piece of it. I figured out how to call a LWC from actions, but it appears that actions only show up on the record instance, NOT on the list view. So if I change my approach to use a button, there are options for custom javascript or a visualforce page. Salesforce discourages the custom javascript due to security issues, so I guess that option is out. Which leaves the only option for the custom list button to call a visualforce page.

Summary:

Can anyone give me any direction on this? First, would it be bad practice to implement a new solution using visualforce (and therefore the button on the list)? Or, ideally, is there a way I can use the button to call a LWC from a list view (since actions don't work for the list view)? Also of thought, if the only way to do this is the call a visualforce page with the button, is there a way I could use the visualforce page to call the LWC? Also, a concern I have with the Visualforce page is that I want this popup to remain over the current page and not redirect.

Any thoughts on the best approach for this would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: did you watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPTQ-Il1eFE ? (and corresponding [blog post](https://codingwiththeforce.com/salesforce-development-tutorial-lwc-how-to-use-lightning-web-components-in-list-view-buttons/))